# AS3 stage screen shot to hard drive save

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, screenshot, hard-drive

I'm working on a drag and drop Flash game, after you place all the movable pieces I want to have a button that allows a person to save a screen shot of the entire stage.

I searched different samples and cant get this code to work.

Here is the AS3

```
snap_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, snapShot );

function snapShot( evt:MouseEvent ):void
{

import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;

var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData (stage.width, stage.height); 
jpgSource.draw(stage); 



var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(85); 
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);

var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream"); 
var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("jpg_encoder_download.php?name=sketch.jpg"); 
jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header); 
jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 
jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream; 
navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "_blank");


}
```

The PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])) 
{ 
// get bytearray 
$jpg = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]; 

// add headers for download dialog-box 
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['name']); 
echo $jpg; 
}
?>
```

I ended up getting this to work, I got rid of the php

```
snap_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, snapShot );

function snapShot( evt:MouseEvent ):void
{

import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder; 



var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.width, stage.height);
jpgSource.draw(stage);
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(80);
var imgByteData:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);
file = new FileReference();

file.save(imgByteData, "Haven_Big_Dream_Map.jpg");




}
```

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with PHP, but it looks like you are using it to save the file. Why not use `FileReference` which gives the user a save dialog right through Flash? Can't help you with the JPG Encode, but if it is something due to the PHP, you could definitely do this using FileReference

Comment: Cool Thanks for the tip I got it to work with this code

'snap_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, snapShot );
 
function snapShot( evt:MouseEvent ):void
{

import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder; 



var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.width, stage.height);
            jpgSource.draw(stage);
            var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(80);
            var imgByteData:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);
            file = new FileReference();
            
            file.save(imgByteData, "imagename.jpg");




}'

Comment: Just so you're aware, all imports should be done outside of a class declaration or at the top of your code in CS5. importing within functions is poor practice and may cause problems

Comment: Cool thanks for the tip. I'm slowly learning.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just rewrite answer of Evan.

Use FileReference to save file after using JPEGEncode or PNGEncode from adobe.corelib on BitmapData. Remember that older versions of FlashPlayer (<10) won't save files on drive!