# How (if possible) do I programatically print out a screenshot of my flash project like when using a right click print command

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I would like to activate this

[image: context menu print]

programatically

Comment: Voted down. If you would have checked the as3 docs you would have found the PrintJob class.

Comment: @BotMaster that is not the same thing that I am asking about. I know about PrintJob and it does not directly emulate the right-click Print... context menu. Basically I'm looking for an easy way out.

Comment: Then you need to rephrase your question since it only means you want to print "LIKE" you do it via the right click menu, it doesn't mean you want to do it via the right click at all. But anyway it is not possible to do what you want.

Comment: @BotMaster "How (if possible) do I programatically print out a screenshot of my flash project ***like*** when using a right click print command"

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a screenshot, it looks like you're going to have to use [BitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html).

Here's an example that will get you started (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16091327/1822214)):

```
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder; 

var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.width, stage.height);
jpgSource.draw(stage);
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(80);
var imgByteData:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);
file = new FileReference();

file.save(imgByteData, "my_screenshot.jpg");
```

Comment: Voted down. PO ask for print.